# calculates between These two columns in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

I want to add a column to the query that calculates between These two columns In the same query ....................................................................

```
  ,isnull(sum(ORDERS.Net_Amount) + 0,0) as orders
  ,isnull(sum (convert(float,(RECEIPTS.Amount))) + 0,0) as recepts
```

IN SQL SERVER

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.[ID_CUSTOMER]
      ,[FIRST_NAME]
      ,[TEL]
      ,[EMAIL]
      ,isnull(sum(ORDERS.Net_Amount) + 0,0) as orders
      ,isnull(sum (convert(float,(RECEIPTS.Amount))) + 0,0) as recepts
      ,[CRIDIT_LIMIT]
      ,[CUSTOMER_SINCE]
      ,[ADRESS]
      ,CUSTOMERS.[state]
  FROM [CUSTOMERS]
LEFT JOIN ORDERS on CUSTOMERS.ID_CUSTOMER = ORDERS.CUSTOMER_ID
LEFT JOIN RECEIPTS on CUSTOMERS.ID_CUSTOMER = RECEIPTS.ID_CUSTOMER
GROUP BY CUSTOMERS.[ID_CUSTOMER]
      ,[FIRST_NAME]
      ,[TEL]
      ,[EMAIL]
      ,[CRIDIT_LIMIT]
      ,[CUSTOMER_SINCE]
      ,[ADRESS]
      ,CUSTOMERS.[state]
```

CUSTOMERS table

```
SELECT [ID_CUSTOMER]
      ,[FIRST_NAME]
      ,[TEL]
      ,[EMAIL]
      ,[IMAGE_CUSTOMER]
      ,[CRIDIT_LIMIT]
      ,[CUSTOMER_SINCE]
      ,[ADRESS]
      ,[Balance]
      ,[state]
  FROM [CUSTOMERS]
```

ORDERS table

```
SELECT [ID_ORDER]
      ,[DATE_ORDER]
      ,[CUSTOMER_ID]
      ,[DESCRIPTION_ORDERS]
      ,[SALEMAN]
      ,[ORDER_TOTAL]
      ,[Discount_Of_Total]
      ,[Total_After_Discount]
      ,[Paid_Up]
      ,[Net_Amount]
      ,[state]
  FROM [ORDERS]
```

RECEIPTS table

```
SELECT [image_state]
      ,[ID_RECEIPT]
      ,[ID_CUSTOMER]
      ,[Date]
      ,[Ref]
      ,[Amount]
      ,[Memo]
      ,[User_Name]
      ,[state]
      ,[Payment_Method]
      ,[Account_ID]
  FROM [RECEIPTS]
```

Comment: First take a basic SQL tutorial. And then come back adding more detail to your question like example data and expected output

Comment: Hive ua your code to correct and your bd architecture

Comment: I update my question

Comment: Please include the `Customers` table.

Comment: Please add a tag for the form of `SQL` that you are using, such as `MySQL`, `SQL-Server`, etc.

Comment: Cross-posted to https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/239998/115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orders and receipts are not really related to each other (the receipt doesn't refer to a specific order), so don't join the two. What you want to do instead is find the order amount and the receipt amount per customer and show them. So aggregate the two tables per customer and outer-join the results to the customer table.

```
 select
   c.id_customer,
   c.first_name,
   c.tel,
   c.email,
   coalesce(o.sum_net_amount, 0) as order_amount,
   coalesce(r.sum_amount, 0) as receipt_amount,
   c.cridit_limit,
   c.customer_since,
   c.adress,
   c.balance,
   c.state
 from customers c
 left join
 (
   select customer_id, sum(net_amount) as sum_net_amount
   from orders
   group by customer_id
 ) o on c.id_customer = o.customer_id
 left join
 (
   select id_customer, sum(amount) as sum_amount
   from receipts
   group by id_customer
 ) r on c.id_customer = r.id_customer;
```

I see you have updated your request now asking also for the difference of the sums. Well, the operator for subtraction in SQL is - little surprising - the minus sign:

```
   coalesce(o.sum_net_amount, 0) - coalesce(r.sum_amount, 0) as diff
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to alias the table (from customers **c**). I've updated my answer.

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
Invalid column name 'customer_id'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
Invalid column name 'customer_id'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'balance'.

Comment: Okay, it's `id_customer`, not `customer_id`, in some tables (you're not consistent with the names). How have you not been able to find this out yourself? As to `balance` I don't know. You are showing a column of that name in `customers`. Is this information incorrect?

Comment: this is good code   thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT Customers.ID_Customer,
       first_name,
       tel,
       email,
       SUM( net_amount ) AS OrdersTotal,
       COALESCE( sumAmount, 0 ) AS PaymentsTotal,
       SUM( net_amount ) - COALESCE( sumAmount, 0 ) AS DifferenceInTotals,
       cridit_limit,
       customer_since,
       adress,
       balance,
       state
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.ID_Customer = Orders.Customer_ID
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ID_Customer,
                   SUM( amount ) AS sumAmount
            FROM Receipts
            GROUP BY ID_Customer
          ) AS sumAmountFinder ON Customers.ID_Customer = sumAmountFinder.ID_Customer
GROUP BY Customers.ID_Customer,
         first_name,
         tel,
         email,
         cridit_limit,
         customer_since,
         adress,
         balance,
         state;
```

This Answer is based on the assumption that every `Customer` will have at least one `Order`, but possibly no `Receipts`.

This statement is essentially the one that you supplied with the following modifications...

I have changed the `JOIN` to `Orders` to an `INNER JOIN`, since I am assuming that each `Customer` will have at least one `Order`. The `LEFT JOIN` is only necessary where you wish to retain all records from the left table that do not have at least one matching record from the right table as defined by the `ON` clause. (Note : If you wish to retain all the records from the right table where there is no matching records from the left table, use a `RIGHT JOIN`).

I have replaced the `JOIN` to the `Receipts` table with a subquery that calculates the total of the `amount` field for each `Customer` in the `Receipts` table.  A `LEFT JOIN` *is* necessary between `Customers` and the results of this subquery as not all `Customers` will have a `Receipt`. In such situations the `LEFT JOIN` will set each of the fields from the subquery in the joined dataset to `NULL`.

Where the `SUM()` function encounters only `NULL` values it returns `NULL`, not `0`. So that `PaymentsTotal` will be set to `0` for records where the `Customer` has no `Receipts`, I have used the `COALESCE()` function. This function will return the first non-`NULL` argument it encounters. Here I have set it to return the total of `amount` where it encounters one, and `0` where it encounters no total `amount`.

I have removed all of the square brackets from your field and table names. They are only required where you have used an otherwise disallowed name, such as names with spaces (use `[Full Name]` instead of `Full Name`) or names that are also reserved by SQL-Server (if you had decided to call `PaymentsTotal` `Sum`, then you would have had to use `AS [Sum]`). Many programmers consider giving fields such names to be bad practice, even when it is possible with `[]`'s, but fortunately you have not used any otherwise names.

I have removed the table names from your `SUM()` calculations. Since only one table has a field called `net_amount`, then it will be a unique field name in the joined dataset, and you will be able to refer to them without specifying the name of the source table as well. Specifying the source table is still necessary in the case of `Customers.ID_Customer` as the joined dataset will have more than one field called `ID_Customer`. Also, you will need to specify the source tables names when creating the joined dataset using the `JOIN`'s.

I have also taken the liberty of changing your capitalisation scheme. Having just about everything in constant upper-case is monotonous to the eye. Using different casing for SQL terms, table names and field names makes recognising each type of statement part much easier, and thus makes debugging code much easier.

Finally, and relatively trivially, cridit is actually spelt credit and adress is actually spelt address.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: I shall update my Answer accordingly in a few minutes.

Comment: Probably.  It may take me a couple of hours, though, as I have an appointment coming up.

Comment: Update posted.  Please get back to me with the results.  I will be back in an hour or two.

Comment: Error corrected, with new code posted.  I am now working on the new explanation.

Comment: Explanation posted.

Comment: Hi Sir, My problem is that I could not add a column to calculate the difference between the amount and the net_amount

Comment: Answer updated.  Is that what you were after?

Comment: yes that what i want but you have change  INNER to LEFT .

Comment: Can you have a `Customer` with no `Orders`?

Comment: Sometimes   You must edit the code to close the question

Comment: Thank you again for solving the problem I am very grateful to you

Comment: You're welcome.  Happy to help.  Please note that if an Answer does indeed solve the problem presented in your Question, and you feel that it is the best quality Answer of those available, then you can accept it as the Answer by clicking on the tick mark near the top of the Answer.  This give the Answerer a small 15 point reward and removes your Question from StackOverflow's list of unanswered Questions.

Comment: done....................

Comment: Thank you!  Have a nice day!

Comment: Are you sure this query gives you correct results? Say for a customer you have two orders with the amounts 100 and 200 and two receipts with the amounts 10 and 20. You join and get 100|10, 100|20, 200|10, 200|20. You sum and get 600|60. Don't you rather want 300|30 instead?

Comment: Thorsten Kettner, You are quite correct.  I took care of that with an earlier version of my Answer and thereafter gave it no thought.  Unfortunately that change did not survive to the currently posted version.  I shall correct this error, and thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Correction posted.  Rewriting explanation now.

Comment: Update explanation posted.